# UIScrollView and touchesBegan / touchesEnded etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` with 2 subviews, let's call it view `A`:

- a basic `UIView`, called `B`
- a `UIScrollView`, called `C`

I overrided the following method in view `A`:

- `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
- `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

When I touch view `B`, `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` get called, but if I touch the `UIScrollView` (view `C`), there are not called.

I know this is the expected behaviour, but I am trying to understand why. I could not find any clear answer on that. Any idea?

Comment: Is view C under view B in terms of layout? Do you call super methods in overridden ones?

Comment: B and C are not overlapping. Yes I call super methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25108078/1702413

Comment: @TonyMkenu : I don't want to disable user interaction on the UIScrollView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have at least 2 options:

1) "By setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` for your scroll view". 
More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25108078/1702413

2) subclass your UIScrollView - for example with this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/ClassScrollViewDelegate.zip

**UPDATE**

Why? Please, read again the documentation:

> "Because a scroll .. it must know whether a touch signals an intent
>   to scroll ... it temporarily intercepts a touch-down event ... .. the
>   scroll view cancels any tracking in the subview and performs the
>   scrolling itself"

**And most important:** **

> **Subclasses** can override the
>   touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:, pagingEnabled, and
>   touchesShouldCancelInContentView: methods

From here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922

Comment: I am not looking for solutions, I am looking to understand why touchesBegan is not called when I touch the UIScrollView

Answer (score 9):

Use the TapGestureRecognizer instead of touchBegan method

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];

- (void)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {  
//handle taps   
}
```

Swift version :

```
let singleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTap:")
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    scrollViewH.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)

func singleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    println("handle taps ")

}
```

Answer (score 7):

if you have scroll view thouchesBegan method will not work because if want scrolling you have to Enable userInteractionEnabled to YES in storyboard. If you make it to NO it'll trigger. So solution is use TapGestureRecognizer
Add this to your viewDidLoad:

```
let singleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "MyTapMethod:")
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    myscrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
```

Then add this MyTapMethod in your controller.

```
func MyTapMethod(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //NSLog("touchesBegan")
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3/4** version:

```
let singleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.tapRecognized))
singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleTapGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
```

And then:

```
@objc func tapRecognized() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this to recognize touch events(began,moved,ended) using pan gesture of the scrollview,

```
Class CustomScrollView:UIScrollView
{

CustomScrollView()
{

 (this.GestureRecognizers[1] as UIPanGestureRecognizer).AddTarget(() => this.PanHandle(this.GestureRecognizers[1] as UIPanGestureRecognizer));     

}


 private void PanHandle(UIPanGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)           
  {
  var touchLocation=gestureRecognizer.LocationInView(this)             

  if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)             
    {              
      //Touches began              
   }      
else if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed)             
   {            
        //Touches Moved              
   }                
 else if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)          
       {              
       //Touches ended               
  }            
 }
     }

Regards,
Ashwin
```