# How can I detect user activity with all the views in UINavigationController and the navigation controller's navigation controls?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I need to be able to detect any activity (i.e. not idle) so that I can reset a countdown timer.

I tried going the `UIWindow` sendEvent route but that's causing way too many side effects. Isn't there a simple way to detect if a view is tapped, button is clicked, the user navigates to the next screen, etc, etc? I don't need to handle the event or anything, I just need to reset the timer if the user is still using the navigation controller. Btw, this particularly navigation controller is being presented by another UIViewController in code.

I tried using UIGestureRecognizer to handle it, but unfortunately, this method doesn't seem to handle the UINavigationController's controls (e.g. next button, back, etc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode & Swift - Detecting user touch of UIView inside of UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061732/xcode-swift-detecting-user-touch-of-uiview-inside-of-uiscrollview)

Comment: I've updated my question. The page you posted doesn't seem to help with UINavigationControllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use own `UIWindow` subclass for this purpose and track user activity by one of the several `UIResponder` methods:

- [`[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest?language=objc)
- [`[UIView touchesBegan:withEvent:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan)
- [`[UIView touchesMoved:withEvent:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621107-touchesmoved)
- [`[UIView touchesEnded:withEvent:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621084-touchesended)

Any parent view can track subviews touch events. For example you can embed your `UINavigationController` to tracking parent view controller.

Or even place `NonTouchableView` over your screen by adding to window:

```
[self.view.window addSubview:myNonTouchableView];
```

Here is example of untouchable view, that can track touch events occurrences:

```
@interface NonTouchableView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate;

@end

@implementation NonTouchableView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Report user activity to self.delegate
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Swift version:

```
class NonTouchableView : UIView {

weak var delegate: Object?

func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    // Report user activity to delegate
    return nil
}

}
```

Comment: I would I do that in Swift? The problem with this approach is that I don't know which view controller is sending the event. So in my special case, I have a password screen that is presented by the same navigation controller and when I use the password screen, the hitTest is being fired and I don't want to reset the timer if it's the password screen being used.

Comment: You should dynamically add and remove `NonTouchableView` in `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` of different view controllers you wanna track. You can write this code once in common parent view controller (`TrackableViewController`). Or implement more complicated logic of adding and removing this tracking views to hierarchy.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without subclassing the UINavigationController? The reason I'm asking is because the UINavigationController is in a framework that I have no access to. All I do it present it and it collects and returns data.

Comment: @u84six yep, just add this view when you need to track, and hide it when not needed. Or you can add it once and enable/disable it with `hidden` property to easily start/stop tracking.