# UITapGestureRecognizer Activate on Immediate Touch?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

The title might be a little confusing, but is there a way I can Get this code to execute the moment I touch the uiview?

```
entry.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.975, y: 0.975)
    speech.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.975, y: 0.975)
```

I have a UIView that I want to simulate a button press. Currently, the way I have it set up, It only triggers once my finger has left the screen

```
func voiceTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    entry.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.975, y: 0.975)
    speech.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.975, y: 0.975)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
        self.entry.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        self.speech.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.975, y: 0.975)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

How to I get the code outside of the animation block to trigger the moment my finger touches the UIView?

Comment: A tap is a tap. Change it to UIGestureRecognizer and switch its state and case changed you update whatever you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Detect tap down and touch up of a UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611601/ios-detect-tap-down-and-touch-up-of-a-uiview)

Comment: You may also want to disable `delaysContentTouchesInView` if you're finding there's a delay. This happens for things like content in scroll views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the methods (*touchesBegan: withEvent:* etc) to detect the received touch in your UIViewController and check if the touch corresponds to the UIView of your interest. And from there you can trigger an action.

[Check this thread how to implement the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061732/xcode-swift-detecting-user-touch-of-uiview-inside-of-uiscrollview)

[Or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611601/ios-detect-tap-down-and-touch-up-of-a-uiview)